# When I install my app, why notification "Allow playing sound" option if always disabled by default?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-settings

When I have just installed my app, the options "`Allow notification badges`", "`allow playing sound`" and "`allow using led light`" are always off by default. Why? how to make those option enabled by default? I'm on android 11. I'm not sure if those options are present in all android device or just present in my android device (xiaomi) if someone can confirm me.

[image: debugger]

Comment: Did you solve problem?

Comment: no unfortunatly :(

Comment: I noticed that if you enable notifications manually and reinstall the application, the system remembers this setting. Hate this.